# Incompatibility between `acmart` and `standalone`

Tags: standalone, debugging, acmart

I am trying to use the `standalone` class together with the `acmart` class (I am using v1.86).
I can use it fine with 1 `tikzpicture` but it outputs an extraneous glyph with 2 `tikzpicture`s and it throws an error with 3.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
%%%%%%%%% THIS ^^^^ WORKS FINE
% \documentclass[class=acmart,tikz]{standalone}
%%%%%%%%%%% THIS ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ IS AN ISSUE
\begin{document}
% One picture is fine with both
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node{A};
\end{tikzpicture}
% Two prints a "2" at the top left corner
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node{A};
\end{tikzpicture}
% Three pictures gives a `Undefined control sequence. [\end{tikzpicture}]` error
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node{A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is that `\shorttitle` is undefined:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\f@nch@olh ->\ACM@linecountL \shorttitle
                                         \strut
l.18 \end{tikzpicture}

?
```

What you get is a usually untrustful message from your front-end.

The 2 is the page number.

```
\documentclass[class=acmart,tikz]{standalone}

\def\shorttitle{} % acmart wants this to be defined

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty} % to remove header and footer

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node{A};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node{A};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node{A};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]